# Only reading in one input from a file in ada

Tags: file-io, ada, procedural-programming

I am having some trouble reading input in from a file. So what I have done is made a proof of concept program, which is a piece of my main program that does much more but I am only having trouble reading the input.
Here is my proof of concept program:

```
WITH Ada.Text_IO; USE Ada.Text_IO;
with ada.Integer_Text_IO; use ada.Integer_Text_IO;
PROCEDURE Open_File IS

subtype idnum is string(1 ..7);
   -- Make short names so that we can show where things come from

   My_File : File_Type;                  -- Name for file in this program
   Os_Name : String        := "My_Data.txt"; -- OS name for the file
   N       : idnum;                        -- Temporary for reading and printing file contents
   EOL : boolean;
   C : character;
BEGIN

   -- Open will raise an ADA.IO_EXCEPTIONS.NAME_ERROR expection
   -- if the file does not exist.

   Open (File => My_File, Mode => In_File, Name => Os_Name);

   LOOP
      EXIT WHEN End_Of_File (My_File);

      Look_Ahead(My_File, C, EOL);
      IF EOL THEN
         Skip_Line;
      ELSE
         IF C = ' ' THEN 
            Get(My_File, C);
         ELSE
            Get (My_File, N);
            Put_Line(N);
         END IF;
      END IF;         
   END LOOP;

   Close (My_File);
END open_file;
```

My data file looks like this: (including the spaces with no new lines after the last id)

```
1234567

       456784a

   6758abc
```

When I compile and run my program only the first id number gets printed to the screen. I have no clue where to check my code because it should continue to get id numbers until the end of the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you encounter an empty line? (also, you have a missing END IF.)

Comment: and `C` and `EOL` are not defined anywhere

Comment: I fixed the "END IF;" part and it is still not reading anything but the first line. I have changed switching the order of my data file to have a empty line before the first id, and it still only reads the first id. Update: Also declared EOL and C

Answer (score 1):

When you `Get` the second (and third, for that matter) line, Data_Error exception will be raised, because `456784a` is not a number, 'a' is not a numeric character. If you want it to be a hexadecimal number, the input should be 16#456784a# (by default).

Comment: Also in the updated version instead of being an integer I am reading in it is a subtype idnum which is a string of length 7. Still having the same problem though.

Comment: A hint: You call Open, End_Of_File, Look_Ahead, Get and Close with My_File. For what file do you then skip a line?

Comment: Ahh YES thank you I had no idea about the skip_line with parameters wow I can't believe it was something that simple.